# Is there an actual file stored to disk when using InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, sftp

My company doesn't want sensitive data to be stored as files unless they're sanitized first. Anything in memory is fair game. So files downloaded from an FTP server must be sanitized in memory before storing it on disk.

I'm using Jsch as my SFTP library and wondered whether or not using InputStream objects actually implies storing a temp file somewhere on disk by the JRE?

Comment: `InputStream` is a very abstract class, so the answer depends on what the actual runtime type of the stream is. You can access it by invoking `getClass().getName()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `InputStream` does *not* imply a file on disk.  That doesn't mean Tomcat or some other intermediary doesn't store it temporarily (or the operating system itself).

The `InputStream` could be backed by a [AudioInputStream, ByteArrayInputStream, FileInputStream, FilterInputStream, InputStream, ObjectInputStream, PipedInputStream, SequenceInputStream, StringBufferInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), or any other kind of `InputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

They do realize that anything in memory can also go into a paging file at any time?

In any case, an InputStream need not generate a temp file.